# Конвертировать строку в Unicode

Tags: c#, кодировка, utf-8

Как я понял, `\u0014\u0003` - это юникод.

Мне нужно конвертировать строку в юникод.

Например, `3` преобразовать в `\u0003`.

Comment: Ничего не понял. `3` и `\u0003` не имеют ничего общего

Comment: В C# все строки являются юникодными (точнее, UTF-16). `\u0014\u0003` — это просто вариант отображения юникодных символов. Символ `3` в таком представлении будет выглядеть как `\u0033`

Comment: Не нужно плодить вопросы, если есть, что добавить, тогда добавляйте в этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "3";
string r = string.Concat(s.Select(c => $@"\u{(int)c:x4}"));
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: `.ToString( "x4" )`

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо, лень было гуглить :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP атата таким быть (:

Comment: а какой string равен \u0003?

Comment: грубо говоря нужно программно указать 3 - \u0003, 4 - \u0004 те последний символ

Comment: Ну тогда приклейте спереди недостающие символы: `"\\u000" + s`. Я не понимаю какую задачу вы решаете

Comment: @АндрейNO есть string "\u0001" + "\u0002" + val + "\u0007" и combobox с выбором чисел (0 - 9) нужно брать число из combobox и вставлять вместо val как "\u000{{то что взяли из combobox}} и получается когда я клею то не работает оператор \u с которым я вообще не знаком, а если вместо val тупо пишу "\u0008" например то все нормально

Comment: @MikeWaters - перенесите свой комментарий в вопрос. Это важная информация, но ее никто не увидит. / `\u` - это не оператор. Это способ записи литерала, который существует _до_ компиляции.